# PL/SQL: How to detect which browser is being used?

Tags: oracle, browser, plsql, detect

I'm using the pl/sql **htp package** to create simple web pages.
Now I need to use different templates based on the device accessing the pages (Desktop Browser or Mobile Blackberry Client ).

Is this possible in pl/sql?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will tell you:

```
owa_util.get_cgi_env('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
```

Answer (score -2):

Having never used oracle or htp, I can't provide much help, but a bit of googling suggests you can use procedure `utl_http.get_header`, and the particular header you are interested in would be `User-Agent`.

I suggest looking up the utl_http package for more information.

Comment: UTL_HTTP is for making outbound HTTP requests from the database. Use the OWA_UTIL package to work with inbound requests.